# C# Console.WriteLine prints a Char type as Integer

Tags: c#, char, console.writeline

I dont understand why is this printing char data type once as char, other time as integer

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char x = 'A';
    int i = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(x);  // A
    Console.WriteLine(true ? x : 0);  // 65 ???
    Console.WriteLine(false ? i : x);  // 65 ???
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I would expect output to be `A, A, A` but the output of above is `A, 65, 65`.  Why?

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation? It would be faster .

Comment: The expression `(condition) ? x : y` can only have one type, determined at compile time. Since you can cast `char` to `int` but not vice versa, that type is `int`. Therefore, the `WriteLine(int)` override is called.

Comment: If you look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), it says, *"Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other."* Since there is an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`, but not the other way around, the type becomes an `int` (implicit conversion means it works without an explicit cast - you can do `int foo = 'A';`, but you can't do `char foo = 1;`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary/conditional operator `?` requires all of the following three operands:

1. An expression that evaluates to a boolean
2. An expression that returns a value of any type
3. An expression that returns a value of the same type as #2

The return value will always be of the same type; that is why #2 and #3 must be the same type.

If the third operand isn't the same type as the second operand, the compiler will look for an implicit cast and use it if possible.

So when you write

```
var x = flag ? 65 : 'A';
```

it is exactly the same as

```
int x = flag ? (int)65 : (int)'A';
```

...and will always return an `int`.

If this were not the case, the result of the `?` could not be assigned to a strongly typed variable, which would be a serious obstacle.

Also, you can**not** write something like this:

```
var x = flag ? 65 : "A"; //Notice it's a string and not a char
```

...because there is no implicit cast from "A" to integer.

Comment: Potentially of interest to OP, if the #2 is casted to an `object` the initial example will give their expected output, but only because `Console.WriteLine` only really cares about `ToString`, the object types returned by the expression will now both be `object` and not different types like `char`/`int`.

Comment: [The operator is `?:`, not just `?`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)