# Console displaying char as an int when using a Conditional Operator ( ?: )

Tags: c#, console-application

I am surprised by the output of the following code

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char x = 'A';
    int i = 0;
    Console.WriteLine (true  ? x : 0);
    Console.WriteLine(false ? i : x); 
}
```

When I was reading the C# interview question I saw this code and the output of above code was

**Output**

```
65
65
```

I am wondering how does that happen.

Can anybody explain me ? Thanks!

Comment: Nitpick: It has nothing to do with ASCII (even though it does).  The Unicode code point for capital A is \u0041.  The decimal equivalent of the hex 0x41 is 65 decimal.  The `char` type is an integral type, and the conditional ternary operator needs compatible types so it considers `'A'` as an integer, rather than a "character".  If you had two characters (something like this: `Console.WriteLine(true ? 'A' : 'B');`), you would have seen `'A'` as the output

Comment: BTW, if you had mixed the string `"A"` with an integer, it wouldn't have compiled, you would have gotten this error: `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'int'`.  It's the fact that characters are implicitly convertible to `int`s that lots of things _Just Work_.  One more historical fact... The "C Language" could do this too, and C# works hard to make sense to us really old C programmers (those of us who bought the first edition of K&R's "The C Programming Language"),

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Console.WriteLine prints a Char type as Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351313/c-sharp-console-writeline-prints-a-char-type-as-integer)

Comment: @John - done sir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'A'` is a `char` and has the value of `65`

However, there is a technical explanation for why this results in an integer (and not the string representation of a char), you can find it in the [ECMA C# specifications](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)

**12.15 Conditional operator**

> The second and third operands, x and y, of the ?: operator **control the
>   type of the conditional expression.**
>
> - If x has type X and y has type Y then,
>
>   - If X and Y are the same type, then this is the type of the conditional expression.
>   - **Otherwise, if an implicit conversion (§11.2) exists from X to Y, but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.**
>   - Otherwise, if an implicit enumeration conversion (§11.2.4) exists from X to Y, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
>   - Otherwise, if an implicit enumeration conversion (§11.2.4) exists from Y to X, then X is the type of the conditional expression.
>   - **Otherwise, if an implicit conversion (§11.2) exists from Y to X, but not from X to Y, then X is the type of the conditional expression.**
>   - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.
> - If only one of x and y has a type, and both x and y are implicitly convertible to that type, then that is the type of the conditional
>     expression.
> - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs

**Example**

```
char Y = 'A';
int X = Y;
Y = X; // compiler error
```

In short, there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `char`, yet there is from `char` to `int`, so it makes sense for the result type to be an `int`